# Retuning multiple variables with Zapier

Tags: zapier

I need to be able to return a few variables based on a code. If code A then return these. If Code B then return these. In no code, return these.

This is what I have so far.

```
if (inputData.code === 'WSDCD-D2DUK') {
  output = 'Company A';
} else if (inputData.code === '6P1CX-5U2TY'){
  output = 'Company B';
}
else {
  output = 'Not Avaliable';
}

return {result: output};
```

And what I need is something like this:

```
if (inputData.code === 'WSDCD-D2DUK') {
  output = 'Company A';
  course = 'ABC'
} else if (inputData.code === '6P1CX-5U2TY'){
  output = 'Company B';
  course = 'XYZ'
}
else {
  output = 'Not Avaliable';
  course = 'Not in one';
}

return {result: output, course};
```

Comment: The bottom code looks like it works as written. are you seeing an error in Zapier?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not define the `course` variable. However, `output` doesn't need to be defined as it is available in the `Code by Zapier` scope.

I've modified the code a slight bit to reflect your use-case.

```js
var inputData = {'code': 'D2DUK'}
//Remove the line above before pasting in the Code step. 
//You will need to configure it in the Zap.

//Defining the variables here.     
let course = '';
let company = '';

if (inputData.code === 'WSDCD-D2DUK') {
  company = 'Company A';
  course = 'ABC'
} else if (inputData.code === '6P1CX-5U2TY'){
  company = 'Company B';
  course = 'XYZ'
}
else {
  company = 'Not Avaliable';
  course = 'Not in one';
}

//Returning the JSON object with the keys company and course.
return {company, course};
```

Comment: @allen-awf If this answer solves your problem, please upvote and mark as correct. ([info here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))